# How to use SSL for many sites using same IP address?

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate

I have one Apache server with one IP address. I want to use a SSL wildcard for SSL on each of the domain aliases. But I read somewhere that a different IP address is required for each site.

Is there a work around for this? Can I use SSL for several sites that use the same IP address or not?

Comment: You're looking for SNI or SANs (Subject Alternative Names).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server Name Identification (SNI) is supported on all new versions of Apache by default. However the trick to getting it to work was that the IP address needs to be nominated with the port assignment:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.10:443
```

Then nominate the IP address for each site:

```
VirtualHost 192.168.0.10:443
```

On my server I wrapped the SSL sites like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost 92.168.0.10:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/alias.example.com
        ServerName some.site.info
        <Directory "/var/www/html/alias.example.com">
            allow from all
            Options None
        </Directory>
        SSLCertificateFile /var/www/certs/example.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/www/certs/example.com.key.nopass
        SSLCACertificateFile /var/www/certs/intermediate.crt
        SSLEngine on
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

The password was removed from the key file to simplify configuration. However to secure the cert files they are stored below the server's document root.

The additional sites should be added inside the "IfModule" wrapper.